# How to make the association in model so I can get all places of user_places's id in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, console

I have 2 tables for example:

user_places

```
----------------
| id | place_id|
----------------
| 1  | 1       |
----------------
| 1  | 5       |
----------------
| 1  | 6       |
----------------
| 2  | 8       |
```

And a places table

```
--------------------------------------------
| id | title   |  description  | image_url |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1       | description1  | image1    |
--------------------------------------------
| 2  | 5       | description2  | image2    |
--------------------------------------------
| 3  | 6       | description3  | image3    |
--------------------------------------------
| ...| ...     | description4  | image4    |
```

How to make the association in both models so I can get all places of user_places's id = 1 in rails console?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look up [`foreign_keys`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), especially pertaining to Rails.

Rails is basically a way for you to interact with a *relational* database. As such, if you know how to correctly structure a relational DB, you'll be able to better understand Rails' ActiveRecord associations, and how they fit into applications.

[image]

--

> How to make the association in both models so I can get all places of user_places's id = 1

You'd do this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :places
end

#app/models/places.rb
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This means you have to change your `user_places` table to the following:

```
#places_users
#user_id | place_id
```

This will allow you to call:

```
$ @user = User.find "1"
$ @user.places #-> 1,5,6
```

--

The other answer recommended a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship. Whilst this allows you to add other data into your `join model`, it means you have to include a `user_places` model for no real reason (at this stage).

I would recommend using [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) for the moment. This limits you to *only* having references in your `join table`, but makes the entire association much simpler:

[image]

The big caveat here is that you'll need to change your `user_places` table to have an alphabetical nameflow (`places_users`), and make sure you only have the two `foreign_keys` as columns: `user_id` | `place_id`

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me understand a lot!.